# How to continue salat if one joins the jamaat late, and imam performs a sajd-e-sahw?

Tags: salat

I would like to know, how do we continue the `salat` if we have joined the *jamaat* late and few *rakats* have missed, and the *imam* performs a *sajd-e-sahw* ?

Should I also perform the *sajd-e-sahw*, and get up later for next *rakat*?

Comment: you can change your intention from Jamaa'at to Furadaa (but not the reverse) at any instant that you want during Salaat Jamaa'at. So when the Imam went to perform his Sajdeh-Sahv you can (and must as you are in the middle of your prayer) continue your prayer in Furadaa and if Sajdeh Sahv was also obligatory for you then after your prayer has finished perform it, according to Shia Fiqh. Read any Fiqh book that you want as reference.

Answer (score 2):

You follow the Imam in all aspects, including Sajd-e-sahw, till he finishes his prayer and you continue with your own. Hence, you need to perform the Sajd-e-sahw with the Imam. This is per the Sunni fiqh. And Allah(swt) knows best.

Comment: You have to show some proofs, hadeeths, scholars' quotations etc.

Comment: @Saif salam and welcome to islam.SE, we suggest you read the [FAQ](http://islam.stackexchange.com/faq).  Here we require answers to contain citations from the Quran, Sunnah, reliable Fatwah, and or from any other reliable Islamic resource.  Please add citations to your answer to raise the quality, thank you.  We look forward to having you as an active participant here Insha'Allah.